# Motor Shield StepMotor

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

[image]

What the two yellow cables as you can see in the picture do not know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of stepper motors: unipolar and bipolar. Bipolars usually have four wires and unipolars have six.

> [image]
>
> --http://hobbymilling.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Unipolar-stepper-motor-windings.png
>
> [image]
>
> --https://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/steppermotorcontrol/pic6.jpg

The motor shield is designed to drive a bipolar motor (4 wires) but the motor is unipolar (6 wires). As you can see in the pictures, if you ignore the middle wire of the unipolar motor, it is the exact same as a bipolar stepper motor.

Comment: Here is the link from the original answer that you rudely deleted. You will read that there is a difference between the two http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/C4A024DA9F197E6286257BC8005DC236. I also +1'd the querstion because you or someone else -1'd it unfairly. It's a good question!

Comment: @VisualMicro please read the comment I left on your answer: “Whilst you link may answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the linked here, and provide the link for citation. I've deleted this answer for now. Feel free to add another answer. Thanks! –  Annonomus Penguin♦ 3 hours ago”

Comment: I read your message and think my post gave an accurate answer which is a link to a very simple overview. You deleted my post and added an incorrect answer. You seem to be purely interested in gaining points for your Annonomus account. You should be brave, tell people who you are, stop deleting correct answers to gain points and give accurate responses.

Comment: Please see the stack exchange policy on link only answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/190823. Your post basically said "there are two configurations, both outlined HERE." If you have an issue, please create a meta post where I and I (and the rest of the community) will be happy to discuss this further. Until then, please post an answer here that is valid without any links that is the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: See above I already posted the link. I think the policy requires accurate answers 1st. It's a long answer and best read via the link I posted. I won't be adding another answer I think the user has the answer now. I am not here to waste people time.